# Are these models nested? (CFA/SEM)

Tags: nested-data, confirmatory-factor

The general question is: If Model 1 has a certain structure, and in Model 2 you free some of the parameters, and fix others, are the models nested?

Specifically in the case I'm dealing with:

One model is a bifactor model (see Reise, 2012), but with two 'general' factors, and the specific-level factors correlated. So: My indicators each load on two factors - 1 of 6 specific factors, and one of 2 'general' factors. The correlations within the specific factors are free.

The second model removes the correlations within the specific factors (i.e., fixes them to zero) and adds a truly general factor (so that all the indicators load on it; so the loadings are freed compared to the previous model).

Are these models nested?

Thanks.

Figures of the models:

MODEL ONE:

[image: Figure or Model 1 - BiFactor Model]

MODEL TWO:

[image: Figure of Model 2 - General Factor Added]

Comment: Can you post figures of your models? That might help make this clearer.